# AWS Sagemaker Endpoint Invocation Latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to understand where the extra time in my Sagemaker invocation is coming from. I'm receiving average round-trip response times of ~350ms.

I'm using Huggingface + Sagemaker, and have used a custom inference.py file to customize the inference script. In the script, I made sure to measure the time it takes to perform inference, and this averages out to ~75ms.

I don't believe that it would take ~275ms for the response to make it round trip, so I'm confused as to what could be taking so long. Is there any tips out there to help direct my search for making the request go as quick as possible?

Comment: Where are you calling the model from? within the cloud or from a local workstation? Did you see in CloudWatch what is Model Latency vs Overhead Latency?

Comment: @OlivierCruchant I tested calling the model locally and from a deployed AWS Elastic Beanstalk app as well, I get this response time in both cases. The model latency at its worst was ~106ms with the overhead latency topping at ~35ms. That's fine, I understand I'll have some of that. Wondering where the other ~140ms went. I understand we need to allow some time for network communication but I don't believe it's that high.

Comment: @AndrewL did you get to know the answer, I have same problem

Comment: @Raj Unfortunately no, I didn't end up finding a solution. I've also moved on to a different company, so I can't provide any other context here.